# Call a subroutine on each character in string - MIPS

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I'm new to MIPS assembly, I want to write a routine that takes the memory address of a string and the memory address of another callback subroutine. This routine will go through every letter in the string and for each letter call the subroutine (this prints the ASCII value of each letter). The pseudo code would look something like this:

```
string_for_each(string, subroutine) {
  for_each_character_in_string {
    subroutine(address_of(character))
  }
}
```

This is what my routine looks like right now:

```
string_for_each:

    addi    $sp, $sp, -4            # PUSH return address to caller
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)

    jal loop

    lw  $ra, 0($sp)                 # Pop return address to caller
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4

    jr  $ra

loop:

    lb  $t1, 0($a0)                 # Get current character
    beq $t1, $zero, end_for_each    # Done when reaching NULL character
    jr  $a1                         # Call callback subroutine
    addi    $a0, $a0, 1             # Increment to get next character in string
    j   loop

end_for_each:   

    jr  $ra                         # Return to caller
```

The thing is that the register $a0 contains the address to the string, and $a1 contains the address to the callback subroutine, and the address to the current character in the string that will be passed to the callback subroutine should also be in $a0. How can $a0 contain both the starting address of the string and the current character at the same time?

The callback subroutine:

```
ascii:  
    .data
STR_the_ascii_value_is:
    .asciiz "\nAscii('X') = "

    .text

    la  $t0, STR_the_ascii_value_is

    # Replace X with the input character

    add $t1, $t0, 8 # Position of X
    lb  $t2, 0($a0) # Get the Ascii value
    sb  $t2, 0($t1)

    # Print "The Ascii value of..."

    add $a0, $t0, $zero 
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    # Append the Ascii value

    add $a0, $t2, $zero
    li  $v0, 1
    syscall


    jr  $ra
```

Comment: _"How can $a0 contain both the starting address of the string and the current character at the same time?"_ Why not just increment `$a0` at the end of each iteration?

Comment: You will need to save `$a0` and `$a1` elsewhere (usually stack) for the duration of the subroutine call.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, I tried something like this to iterate through the string:
    lb $t1, 0($a0)        
    beq $t1, $zero, end
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
But the current character gets stored in $t1 this way?

Comment: @Michael I just get the first character in the string by doing this.

Comment: Without seeing the complete MIPS code it's impossible to determine what's wrong.

Comment: @Michael Added what I've got for the routine so far in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to save `$a0` and `$a1` elsewhere (usually stack) for the duration of the subroutine call. Also, your `loop` isn't a subroutine, no reason to call it using `jal`. On the other hand, the callback **is** a subroutine, you should call it using `jalr`. Something along these lines should work:

```
string_for_each:

    addiu $sp, $sp, -12             # Need 3 locals for $a0, $a1 and $ra
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)                 # Store $ra
    sw  $a1, 8($sp)                 # Store $a1

loop:
    sw  $a0, 4($sp)                 # Store $a0 as it will be used for argument
    lb  $t0, 0($a0)                 # Get current character
    beq $t0, $zero, end_for_each    # Done when reaching NULL character
    jalr $a1                        # Call callback subroutine
    lw  $a0, 4($sp)                 # Reload $a0
    lw  $a1, 8($sp)                 # $a1 could have changed (calling convention)
    addi $a0, $a0, 1                # Increment to get next character in string
    j   loop

end_for_each:
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)                 # Reload return address to caller
    addiu $sp, $sp, 12              # Free locals
    jr  $ra
```

Comment: Ah, I see! That makes a lot more sense. Thank you!

Comment: When running the code I get the error message `Exception occurred at PC=0x0040027c`, which is at the line `lb  $t2, 0($a0)  # Get the Ascii value` in the callback subroutine (I added the code for this callback subroutine,`$a1`, in the question). This is followed by the error `Bad address in data/stack read: 0x00000041`. I'm not sure what this means, any idea? Been trying to play around with the code but the error messages remains.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have written the code so it passes the actual character, not the address to the callback. Fixed the code.

Comment: Store/reload of `$a0` inside the loop is rather inefficient.  Normally we'd save `$s0` (or other call-preserved register) at the start of the function, outside the loop, and `move $s0, $a0`, using `$s0` as the pointer in the loop.  You do need the pointer value in `$a0` as the function arg, though, so this is smaller total code size but executes more instructions.